# & operator cannot be applied to constants in C

Tags: c, pointers, constants

According to *The C programming language by Kernighan and Ritchie*, page 94

> & operator cannot be applied to constants

```
const int u = 9;
printf ("\nHello World! %u ", &u);
```

So, why does that work?

Comment: u is normally used for unsigned integers....

Comment: When the book says constants it means *literal* constants. A variable is still a variable, even if it's `const` qualified.

Comment: "constant" and "const-qualified variable" are different

Comment: As a hint, please do some research about *lvalues* and *rvalues*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misunderstanding between `constant` and `const`. Both are different things in C language.

> & operator cannot be applied to constants

In C programming, It means you cannot use `&(address operator)` on the literal constant to get the address of the literal constant.

For examples :

```
&10
```

**or**

```
&('a')
```

If you use `&` operator over literal constant, the compiler will give an error because constant entity does not have corresponding address.

Comment: `'a'` is also an int constant.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Draft Standard §6.5.3.2 ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p1), use of the address operator must obey the following constraint:

> The operand of the unary **&** operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a **[]** or unary ***** operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the **register** storage-class specifier.

The meaning of *lvalue* is given in [§6.3.2.1 ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1):

> An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than **void**) that potentially designates an object.

According to [§3.15 ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15p1) an *object* is a:

> region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values.

Now, a *constant* is not an lvalue; a constant has a value, but a constant does not indicate an object, and a value can't be *assigned* to a constant. 
So, a constant is not a function designator, is not the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, and is not an lvalue, which means that taking the address of a constant is a constraint violation. A diagnostic message must be issued by a conforming implementation.

On the other hand, given `const int u = 9;`, `u` is a `const` qualified variable of type `int`. This declaration *does* reserve storage for the variable, and `u` is an lvalue. The use of `const` does not indicate that `u` is a constant, but that the object indicated by the identifier `u` is `const` (which is not the same thing). It may be better to think of `const` qualified variables as "read-only"; this is a promise made by the program that the object indicated by `u` will not be modified. Since `u` is an lvalue here (that is not a bit-field, and is not declared with the `register` keyword), it is fine to take its address with `&u`.

Do note that the posted code has undefined behavior, since the correct `printf()` conversion specifier for printing addresses is `%p`; its argument must be cast to `(void *)`. Mismatched conversion specifiers and arguments lead to undefined behavior. So, the correct code would be:

```
const int u = 9;
printf ("\nHello World! %p ", (void *) &u);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, in order to get variable's address in the memory, we can apply pointer to any of them, coz CPU allocates memory for all of them. On the other hand this question has already been asked.

**The term "constant" in C indeed means only literal constants, like 2, for example. A const-qualified object is not a "constant" in C terminology**

[Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814748/using-addressof-with-const-variables-in-c)